# Where should I ask about port forwarding?

Tags: support, site-recommendation

I need to ask a question about network port forwarding, but I don't know where to ask it.

- [Network Engineering?](https://networkengineering.stackexchange.com)
- [Super User?](https://superuser.com)

Somewhere else completely?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, those two sites (and [Server Fault](https://serverfault.com)) come to mind. It's largely a matter of whether you're asking a 'professional' or 'consumer' question:

> #### Network Engineering Stack Exchange is for asking questions about professionally managed networks in a business environment.
>
> ...
>
> *(Note: All questions about RESIDENTIAL/HOME networking and CONSUMER-grade equipment, are explicitly **OFF**-topic.)*

(from the [Network Engineering Help Center](https://networkengineering.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic))

> Server Fault is for questions about **managing information technology systems in a business environment.**
>
> If your question is about:
>
> - managing the hardware or software of servers, workstations, storage or networks
>
> ...
>
> and is not about:
>
> - consumer workstations or networking (which belong on our sister site, [Super User](https://superuser.com/))

(from the [Server Fault Help Center](https://serverfault.com/help/on-topic))